# why do laravel adds ";" when i include a customed navbar?

Tags: laravel, laravel-5.3, bootstrapping

[image: ;]while using @include in laravel, ";" is included automatically before and after my navbar what gives a margin-top for my element.

[image: laravel :]

[image: HTML Display]

Comment: do you even need ; in laravel?  https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/blade#including-sub-views

Comment: laravel is adding it by default

Comment: @include('includes.main-navbar')   do not use ; at the end

Comment: thank you bro @tech_Love

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you do not need `;` in laravel.

https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/blade#including-sub-views

`@include('includes.main-navbar')` do not use ; at the end